# java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl]

Tags: jsf, exception, glassfish

I got this error from GlassFish while (re)deploying an application:

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.ObjectFactory$ConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl could not be instantiated: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
```

I stopped GlassFish, clean and build the application, deployed the application and this was the result.

Comment: It looks like an error occurs when trying to load some configuration file. `org.apache.xerces` is an XML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird, I had to undeploy an other project what had a xercesImpl.jar as library and the application I was trying to deploy, deployed without even a warning...
Apparently GlassFish has it's own XML-parser and it conflicts when it detects other XML-parsers.